# Background color change for Angular tabs

Tags: html, css, angular

I am very new to html and css ,  I have used angular-tabs-component for creation of tabs,so now i want to change background color of tab..can some one suggest me how to do.here is my code...

HTML:

```
<tabs (currentTabChange)='onSelectChange($event)'>
        <tab tabTitle="Live">
        </tab>
</tabs
```

Comment: create a class with background-color property and apply it to the tab div

Comment: If you want to change the tab color when it's active, inspect the active tab and find the class that's making it active. Style that class with desired `backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 0):

Add class `tab` to tab tag-

```
<tabs (currentTabChange)='onSelectChange($event)'>
    <tab tabTitle="Live" class="tab-background">
    </tab>
</tabs
```

and then in the css of that component add -

```
.tab-background {
    background-color: red;
}
```